# Trying to parse href from json file in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, parsing, google-places-api

I have a program that I want to collect individual pieces of data from the Google Places API. I am able to get most of the attributes that I want, however, whenI try to get the 'html_attributions", I get the error:

```
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I used the same formatting for this line as I did the other lines, so I don't understand why it's throwing this error.

This is my code:

```
    for n in range(len(data['results'])):
            location = []
            address = data['results'][n]['vicinity']
            address = address[: address.rfind(", ")]
            coords_lat = str(data['results'][n]['geometry']['location']['lat'])
            coords_lng = str(data['results'][n]['geometry']['location']['lng'])
            url_href = ''
            if str(data['results'][n]['photos']['html_attributions']):
                url_href = str(data['results'][n]['photos']['html_attributions'])
            location = [address, coords_lat, coords_lng, url_href]
            return location
```

This is the JSON data:

```
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.3151516,
           "lng" : -79.9131046
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.31669727989272,
              "lng" : -79.91206752010727
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.31399762010727,
              "lng" : -79.91476717989272
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
     "id" : "d66fce15477e5e481e618cdf7483809c6581060c",
     "name" : "Two Men & A Truck",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true,
        "weekday_text" : []
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 667,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116914873550616940396/photos\"\u003eTwo Men and A Truck\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAANR4eDG2XMLwt16x9WXQNPH45QExLrJOmBUaHYF2lNXejPRGm6G1D8WT6EhVDruj8SHkNjRwmE_BcwavNs0Olq2PJveNVFG9GFKtXoBzF1w9JLjTKZiEFxmKZho-mvTPJEhCXKgV1x1fFgzcOYasfGnjzGhQ9gezZ8T16Qyogf9CTS4OiSrpK1g",
           "width" : 1024
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJ510ZCi6dLIgRYNowStOOqxQ",
     "rating" : 2,
     "reference" : "CmRbAAAAU36QBuW3xN3We55B8WvA_6OAFkMJx-dS2u0REb8xFjdqxkRjQe4kIlSwx1lvu9DL8GIckgpT_pspgN618vJF06m4BZZ-pwG8gIllEHHmjhCSXX44PmeOXKeBirjeHHSJEhBKlLGuJ3HrpwKj1DnYqWpSGhSLQhCw8j3ercmdZS-c_bHNZ-BnOA",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "types" : [ "car_repair", "store", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "50 Dundas St E, Dundas"
  }
```

Comment: Can we see the "data" payload that contains the "html_attributions" key? My guess is you're parsing the payload slightly wrong.

Comment: just added the JSON data. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Look closely at your JSON data - there is a list inside the 'photos' element, which is why 'html_attributions' is not a child element

Comment: so if I did str(data['results'][n]['photos'[1]]), should that work? Or how would I get the data from 'html_attributions'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your payload, to get the "html_attributions", assuming your parsing data['results'][n] correctly (because you didn't show the entire json payload), you'd have to do something like

```
data['results'][n]['photos'][0]['html_attributions'][0]
```